# Linux Init Script - Execution Time (etc/rc0.d/S01)

Tags: linux

We have a plan to do an automation that automatically sends data to cloud storage once the server will shut down or halt.

We will use the common:

ln -s /etc/ec2-termination /etc/rc0.d/S01ec2-termination

My Question is, let say my ec2-termination take 10 Mins to execute. Is the system wait to the said init script to complete before it will shutdown?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

No the server want wait. The usual termination time is ~ 2min and not longer.
https://github.com/miglen/aws/blob/master/ec2/run-script-on-ec2-instance-termination.md